# DropDownlist getting value by id

Tags: jquery

i try to retrieve value of dropdownlist value but it prints undefined why ?

```
var selected =  $("#checkedSelect option:selected").val();
```

i take like that

```
{foreach from=$allTypes value=types}
                        <option id="checkedSelect" value="{$types.id}">{$types.type}</option>
                           {/foreach}
```

Comment: we need something more than that...

Comment: Do you want to retrieve that selected option' value or all? `$(#checkbox').val()` would return the value for selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    var x;
    $("#checkedSelect").change(function(){
         x = $(this).val();
         alert(x);
    });
```

Comment: #checkedSelect refers to a `select` tag?

Comment: omg i put id to options sorry. Thank you